# Is there an English language edition of the entirety of Lem's "The Star Diaries" in a single volume?

Tags: publishing, stanislaw-lem

I own a copy of *Memoirs of a Space Traveler*, Harcourt Brace Jovanovich, 1982, in hardback. This book is composed of several stories from the Polish version of Stanislaw Lem's *The Star Diaries* translated into English. It contains a note from the publisher stating

> The pieces of this book -- the two Voyages of Ijon Tichy, his
> reminiscences, his open letter -- all appeared in the 1971 Polish
> edition of Dzienniki gwiazdowe (The Star Diaries) but were not
> included in the British and American editions titled *The Star
> Diaries* in 1976. The present book, in effect, constitutes the second
> volume of Lem's work of that name.

I take it the note is referring to the first English edition of *The Star Diaries* published by Seabury Press in 1976.

Has all of the Lem material been subsequently published as a single English language volume some time after that publisher's note from 1982? Also I am curious if there is some reason why the 1976 edition only contained a subset of the original Polish content to begin with.

Comment: Actually, there's no such book even in Polish :D

Comment: What is the Polish publication history of this material?

Comment: Quite complicated, apparently. But, for clarity,  you ask about a book with all Ion Tichy short stories, not just combining memoires and diaries?

Comment: yes. Although i'd be interested if Diaries + Memoirs exists in English -- it seems that it doesnt though. Plus there a few stories that are not in either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [ISFDb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?23841) the answer is no.  Note that while ISFDb may not have all e-books or self-published works, it's pretty comprehensive for published English-language SF, certainly for older works like these.  Searching [Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=stanislaw+lem&sprefix=stanisl%2Caps%2C160), which will mostly have newer works, especially e-books, doesn't turn up anything missing.

If we look at "[The Twelfth Voyage](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?78405)" (Polish "Podróż dwunasta") we see it is only ever listed as published in [*The Star Diaries*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?308373), while "[Further Reminiscences of Ijon Tichy I](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?78434)" (Polish "I (Profesor Corcoran)") is only published in [*Memoirs of a Space Traveler*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?423699).

There are also a number of stories not in either of those collections, for instance "[Ostatnia Podroz Ijona Tichego](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1393985)" (1996), translated in English as "[Ijon Tichy's Last Journey to Earth](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?852227)" (1999) which appears to only have been published in *Altair* Issue Four, and "[V: (Tragedia pralnicza)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?836199)" (1963), translated to English as "[The Washing-Machine Tragedy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2251180)" (1981) published only in *The New Yorker*, November 30, 1981.

The ISFDb list also includes a few stories, such as "[Podróż dwudziesta szósta i ostatnia](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?835821)" (1954) (approximate translation: "The Twenty-sixth and Last Voyage") and "[Profesor A. Dońda: (Ze wspomnień Ijona Tichego)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?847030)" (1974) (approximate translation "Professor A. Donda: From the Memoirs of Ijon Tichy") which do not appear to have ever been translated into English.

Although the ISFDb page for original collection of Ijon Tichy stories, [*Dzienniki gwiazdowe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?24155) claims it was split into 2 books when published in English translation

> The English language version was published in two volumes. The first volume was published as "Star Diaries" and the second one as "Memoirs of a Space Traveller" in the UK and "Memoirs of a Space Traveler" in the US.

the contents of this edition seem to only include the 12th, 13th, 14th and 22nd through 26th Voyages, and a number of unrelated works. (Specifically, none of the stories that show up in *Memoirs* appear in this edition.)  The ISFDb page does mention "The contents were expanded by new stories and cut out some obsolete ones over the course of time." but only 2 distinct Polish editions are described, which may be down to the weakness of ISFDb for non-English works.

*Star Diaries* + *Memoirs* appears to be closer to a split of the 1982 collection [*Dzienniki gwiazdowe: Wydanie rozszerzone*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?251798) even if that edition appeared later.  (This edition also includes a number of stories not translated to English.)

So, unfortunately the answer is "no."  There is not only no single-volume work including the stories from *Star Diaries* and *Memoirs*, there appear to be a number of stories not included in either, some of which have never even been translated into English.